# horizontally laid out absolute buttons just layering on top of each other

Tags: html, css, button, checkbox

I am setting up toogle button by absolutely positioning labels on top of checkboxes. I need  them to horizontally aligned but they are just layering on top of each other.

```
<ul style="display: block; float: left;">
        <li style="display: inline-block;">
          <div class="btn_wrapper">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="newest" name=""/>
            <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default" for="newest">Newest</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li style="display: inline-block;">
          <div class="btn_wrapper">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="popular" name=""/>
            <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default" for="popular">Popular</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li style="display: inline-block;">
          <div class="btn_wrapper">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="price" name=""/>
            <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default" for="price">Price</label>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>


ul {
 display: block;
 li {
   display: inline-block
.btn_wrapper {
      position: relative;
      clear: both;

      label {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #CCC;
      }

      input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
      }

      input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
        color: $shop_color_text_strong;
      }
    }
}
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Everything in your `<li>`s are positioned absolutely and so are outside of the flow, hence there is nothing holding the `<li>` open. So in fact the li's are sitting side by side but they have no width.

Comment: To fix it you can add a different `left` value for each or change the positioning to something like `display:inline-block;`

Comment: ok, great so if I give the <li>s an arbitrary width of 100px they separate. How can I get the li with to just be the width of it's contents?

Comment: yeah, I already tried width: auto and it had the same results... layered

Comment: It seems to work fine when I paste your code into a new html file. Did you try using the inspector to see if some CSS is overriding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up going with. Basically adding display: none to my inputs and removing the absolute position from the label it worked out fine.

```
ul {
      display: block;
      li.filter_btn {
        margin-left: -2px;
      }
      li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        height: 30px;
        label {
          display: block;
          cursor: pointer;
          top: 5px;
          left: 5px;
          z-index: 1;
          width: auto;
          background-color: #CCC;
        }

        input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
          display: none;
        }

        input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
          color: $shop_color_text_strong;
        }
      }
    }
```